# JavaFX ListView does not render enough cells to fill its viewport

Tags: java, listview, javafx, javafx-8

I have this music playing app that displays artists and albums in a grid. I've created this grid using a ListView and custom ListCells. However, the ListView does not seem to render more than 2 cells when it is initialized even though its height is great enough to render 3 or 4 rows depending on the size of your screen. The ListView does, however, render the remaining cells when one of the first 2 cells is hovered over. Take a look at the link below to see the issue in action.

[demo of the issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zvOuz.gif)

I've checked the height of the ListView and it is indeed expanding to fill its parent, so I believe there is something funky going on in the way that the ListView decides which cells need to be rendered. I'm hoping to discover a way to force the ListView to render the correct number of cells if that is the underlying issue, or if there is a mistake in my code, it'd be great to have some light shed on that too. I've posted the code for my controller and my custom ListCell below.

Controller that initializes the ListView:

```
public class ArtistsController implements Initializable {

    @FXML
    private ListView<ArrayList<Artist>> grid;

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {

        List<Artist> artists = Library.getArtists();
        Collections.sort(artists);

        grid.setCellFactory(x -> new ArtistListCell<>());

        ObservableList<ArrayList<Artist>> rows = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
        ArrayList<Artist> row = new ArrayList<>();
        int col;

        for (int i = 0; i < artists.size(); i++) {
            col = i % 5;
            if (col == 0) {
                row = new ArrayList<>();
                rows.add(row);
            }
            row.add(artists.get(i));
        }

        grid.setItems(rows);
    }
}
```

Custom ListCell:

```
public class ArtistListCell<T extends ArrayList<Artist>> extends ListCell<T> {

    private T item;

    public ArtistListCell() {
        this.getStyleClass().setAll("artist-list-cell");
    }

    @Override
    protected void updateItem(T item, boolean empty) {
        super.updateItem(item, empty);
        if (empty || item == null) {
            setText(null);
            setGraphic(null);
        } else if (!item.equals(this.item)) {
            this.item = item;
            HBox row = new HBox();
            item.forEach(artist -> {
                VBox cell = createCell(artist);
                row.getChildren().add(cell);
            });
            setGraphic(row);
        }
    }

    private VBox createCell(Artist artist) {

        VBox cell = new VBox();
        Label title = new Label(artist.getTitle());
        ImageView image = new ImageView(artist.getArtistImage());
        image.imageProperty().bind(artist.artistImageProperty());
        VBox imageBox = new VBox();

        title.setTextOverrun(OverrunStyle.CLIP);
        title.setWrapText(true);
        title.setPadding(new Insets(10, 0, 10, 0));
        title.setAlignment(Pos.TOP_LEFT);
        title.setPrefHeight(66);
        title.prefWidthProperty().bind(this.widthProperty().subtract(102).divide(5));

        image.fitWidthProperty().bind(this.widthProperty().subtract(102).divide(5));
        image.fitHeightProperty().bind(this.widthProperty().subtract(102).divide(5));
        image.setPreserveRatio(true);
        image.setSmooth(true);

        imageBox.prefWidthProperty().bind(this.widthProperty().subtract(102).divide(5));
        imageBox.prefHeightProperty().bind(this.widthProperty().subtract(102).divide(5));
        imageBox.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        imageBox.getChildren().add(image);

        cell.getChildren().addAll(imageBox, title);
        cell.setPadding(new Insets(10, 10, 0, 10));
        cell.getStyleClass().add("artist-cell");
        cell.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);

        cell.setOnMouseClicked(event -> {
            // do something
        });

        cell.setOnDragDetected(event -> {
            // do something
        });

        return cell;
    }
}
```

Comment: How large are the images and how do you load them?

Comment: They're 300x300 pixel .jpgs and they're about 20KB each. They are being loaded like this: Image image = new Image("file path goes here");

Comment: Could be a issue with loading the images nontheless. Try ensuring the images are loaded before showing the scene, e.g. by storing them in a map and getting them in `createCell` and check, if this changes the behavior. (I guess you're creating the images in `createCell` by using the image constuctor right now.) Furthermore if the `createCell` method is not to large, could you add it (or a simplified version allowing to reproduce the issue) to the question?

Comment: Ok I filled in most of the createCell method. Also, the images aren't loaded in createCell. They're loaded at the start of the app, then theyre retrieved by artist.getArtistImage().

Answer (score 0):

I put together a test and experienced this issue using a single static image for the Artists. If I replaced the row building in the ListCell with a simple rectangle it worked okay, so the bottleneck appears to be building your HBox/VBox cells.

Moving the call to setCellFactory after grid.setItems seems to resolve it.

```
grid.setItems(rows);
grid.setCellFactory(x -> new ArtistListCell<>());
```

I'd say doing it this way is calling for another layout pass, whereas the other way around it doesn't have all the information it needs to calculate properly?

You may get different results using your proper image loading if it's taking time. If so, perhaps using a placeholder image if you're still experiencing it?

Comment: This didn't solve my issue, but I've narrowed down the issue to the two lines in createCell in which the ImageView's fitWidthProperty and fitHeightProperty are bound. Replacing either of these with a setFitWidth or setFitHeight seems to make the listview load more cells. But those bindings were added so that the grid would be able to resize

Comment: Perhaps try binding the size of the HBox to the size of the ArtistListCell, then the VBox cell to the size of the HBox, that might cause a cascade of size updates? It seems to be skipping one somewhere down the chain so the values never get updated in the bindings.